# JS: обернуть найденные внутри строки ссылки в элемент <a href=""></a>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ссылки, работа-с-текстом

Помогите, пож-та, с решением задачи.

Проблема: 
React-компонент на вход принимает строку, введённую пользователем.
Строка содержит простой текст, переводы строки, ссылки.
На выходе необходимо получить ту же строку, с сохранением переносов, а ссылки необходимо обернуть в тег "a".
На первый взгляд вполне тривиальная задачка, но я столкнулся с трудностью.

Мой алгоритм решения проблемы:

1. Полученную строку превратить в массив, разбив строку по словам.
2. Пройтись map'ом по массиву и проверить регуляркой каждый элемент: если слово - это валидный урл, то обернуть его в "a", если нет, то обернуть его в "span".
3. На выходе получаем массив слов, каждое из которых обёрнуто в "span" или "a".

Недостаток этого решения в том, что здесь я на каждое слово создаю отдельную дом-ноду, а также теряю переносы строк (т.е. текст на выходе после рендеринга будет идти "сплошняком", даже если юзер вставлял переносы строк, т.к. я их обрезаю при создании массива).

Мой вариант решения на repl: https://repl.it/repls/IllegalMiserlyUlyssesbutterfly

```
const message = 'а вот урл https://superurl.com а вот \n как бы и не урл!http://wwwkokoko.ru';

const decorateMessage = message => {
    const messageBlock = message.replace(/\r|\n/g, ' ').split(' ');
    const regExp = /^(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;

    return messageBlock.map(m => {
        return regExp.test(m)
          ? `<a className='link' href="${m}" target="_blank">${m}&nbsp;</a>`
          : `<span className='muted'>${m}&nbsp;</span>`
    })
};

console.log(
  'result: ', decorateMessage(message)
);
```

Хотелось бы из входных данных на выходе получить просто одну текстовую ноду, с сохранением переносов строки и обёрнутые в "a" ссылки, если они внутри этой ноды есть. Вроде всё просто, но не приходит в голову как такую проблему решают в других инструментах.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: А не хочешь ответ принять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно считать ссылкой всё, до первого пробельного символа:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[parseLinks]')
  .forEach(el => {
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(
      /\b(https?\:\/\/\S+)/mg, 
      '<a href="$1">$1</a>'
    );
  });
```

```html
<div parseLinks>
  Ссылка: http://example.org/
</div>
```

Comment: Здесь так не получится, к сожалению, ведь я не работаю с домом на прямую. Это реакт, просто js. По сути, вернуть мне нужно элемент виртуального дома. Хотя, может быть можно доработать это решение до моей ситуации...

Comment: Ну так уберите работу с  DOM, в чём проблема-то? replace - одна строчка

Comment: Ну так себе по DOM'у лазить в реакте...

Comment: @Qwertiy, при чём тут react? или DOM при чём здесь? Ответ содержит простую синтаксическую конструкцию с регулярным выражением. В качестве демонстрации работы этой конструкции используется DOM. Я никому не предлагал тащить это as-is куда бы то ни было.

Comment: @vp_arth, react при тегах вопроса.

Comment: У меня ссылка находиться внутри строки где есть тег p и регулярка неправильно отрабатывает, подскажи как исправить. Пример строки: <p>примерыный текст https://www.youtube.com</p> а результат сейчас такой: <p>ewfwefwefwe ewfwe wef wefwe fwe <a href="https://www.youtube.com</p" target="_blank">https://www.youtube.com</p</a>>

Answer (score 3):

Обработка кавычек не предусмотрена, поскольку в общем случае непонятно, что с ними делать. Формально, url не может содержать незаэскейпенные кавычки, поэтому можно было бы по ним обрывать адрес, с другой стороны вопросы вызывает логика, связанная со знаками препинания перед кавычками: её можно оставить или наоборот убрать предполагая что url заключается в кавычки не с точки зрения естественного языка, а именно для корректной группировки (например, адрес заканчивается на точку). Так что соответствующие символы надо добавить в регулярку самостоятельно в этом районе: `[.,?!;:()]*(?:\s|$))[^\s]`.

```js
class WithLinks extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var res = []
    
    this.props.text && this.props.text.replace(/((?:https?:\/\/|ftps?:\/\/|\bwww\.)(?:(?![.,?!;:()]*(?:\s|$))[^\s]){2,})|(\n+|(?:(?!(?:https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|\bwww\.)(?:(?![.,?!;:()]*(?:\s|$))[^\s]){2,}).)+)/gim, (m, link, text) => {
      res.push(link ? <a href={(link[0]==="w" ? "//" : "") + link} key={res.length}>{link}</a> : text)
    })
  
    return <div className="user-text">{res}</div>
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { text: "Возможно, http://сайт.рф? Ну или http://сайт.рф?id=67 - вроде парсится\nНу и не без www.google.ru." }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <textarea value={this.state.text} onChange={e => this.setState({ text: e.target.value })} />
        <WithLinks text={this.state.text} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: vertical;
  height: 40vh;
}

.user-text {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<main id=root></main>
```

Разметка получается вот такая:

[image: скриншот разметки]

Comment: Ну и за что минус?