# Регулярное выражение C# URL

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, url, кириллица

Нужно отличать обычный текст от url, но не слишком придирчиво(т.е. пусть лучше проскочит текст, нежели url будет принят за текст)

но вот только лучшая регулярка с этого сайта https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex падает в эксепшн "Недостаточно шестнадцатеричных цифр"
а все остальные, в том числе и с других сайтов, не пропускают слишком много url-адресов, в том числе и адреса https://ru.stackoverflow.com (похоже из-за кириллицы в ссылках на вопросы) или тот-же https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

вот мой код, который даже https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask не пропускает

```
string regex = @"@^(https?|ftp)://[^\s/$.?#].[^\s]*$@iS";
if (Regex.IsMatch(selectedText, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
...
}
```

Comment: А зачем тут вообще регулярка? Есть же `Uri` с его методами, например `Uri.TryCreate()`.

Comment: хм, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 2):

Регулярное выражение для поиска ссылок выглядит [вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594686/178988):

```
(https?:\/\/|ftps?:\/\/|www\.)((?![.,?!;:()]*(\s|$))[^\s]){2,}
```

А посмотреть, как оно работает можно тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1003343/178988.

Answer (score 1):

Вот код, который работает, спасибо EvgeniyZ

```
 var test = new Uri(selectedText);
 if (Uri.TryCreate(selectedText, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out test))
 {
  ///
 {
```

Comment: Эм.. Это создание url, а не поиск ссылок в тексте.

Comment: @Qwertiy А речь разве шла про поиск в тексте? Судя по `Нужно отличать обычный текст от url` автору надо было просто узнать "asd" является ссылкой или нет, без поиска.

Comment: Кстати в этом ответе лучше убрать `var test = new Uri(selectedText);`, а `out test` заменить на `out var test`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, не знаю, кажется, я в вопросе вместо "отличить" прочитал "отделить". Что-то не представляю, в каком случае для целой строки надо проверять, является она url'ом или текстом. Могла бы быть валидация, но по контексту не похоже.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку

а вот суть задачи состояла в том, чтобы отличить строку с текстом от строки с ссылкой

Comment: @Qwertiy

пользователь выделяет ссылку, нажимает хоткей и програма должна среагировать
а вот на просто текст реагировать не надо