# regexp для валидации URL

Tags: регулярные-выражения, url, валидация

Написал регулярное выражение для валидации URL (не URI), некоторое время тестировал - вроде все нормально. Но настораживает, что получилось достаточно короткое. В сети есть примеры - просто монстры.

**EDIT:**

```
/^https?:\/\/([a-z0-9-]([a-z0-9-]|(?<!\.)\.)+?(?<!\.)\.[a-z]{2,10}(:\d{1,5})?$)|(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(:\d{1,5})?$)/
```

Просьба проверить, какие неправильные варианты регулярка пропустит, и наоборот - какие правильные варианты она она не пропустит.

Две оговорки:

- <del>адреса вида https://ip-адрес регулярка не проверяет</del>
- корневые домены имеют длину от 2 до 10 символов (кстати, а как правильно?)

Comment: Да нет уже давно никаких ограничений. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594686/178988. И вот тут можно посмотреть, как работает: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1003343/178988.

Comment: По тамошней ссылке URL вида `http://.сайт.рф` считается правильным. А это не так, imho. Тоже касается и URL вида `http://сайт.рф.`, плюс ко всему там парсер URI а не URL.

Comment: Точка в конце является допустимой - на эту тему даже в сафаре узявимость была. Если открыть `https://www.youtube.com./`, то они делают 301й редирект (раньше ломалась реклама и комменты), способ стал известен как обход рекламы, так что прикрыли. Про точку в начале не уверен, у меня её при переходе убирает сам хром. Можно добавить `(?!\.)` после протокола. Что подразумевается под URI и URL? По моим представлениям всё, что можно вставить в адресную строку браузера, после чего оно откроется как сайт, является URL.

Comment: https://wiki.merionet.ru/servernye-resheniya/36/url-i-uri-v-chem-razlichie/ ... и да, а по моей регулярке есть чего сказать?

Comment: Ну `www.` вместо протокола надо вычистить? Тогда будет URL?

Comment: не-не-не ... URL = адрес сайта, URI = адрес сайта + все остальное, что ведет к ресурсу.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129363/discussion-between-majestio-and-qwertiy).

Comment: То что вы тут валидируете это не URL, а протокол + домен.

Comment: К тому же неверно. В домене не должно быть подчёркиваний, зато может быть номер порта

Comment: Подредактировал. Убрал возможность успешной валидации с подчеркиваниями, добавил распознавания ip-адресов как части URL, и добавил валидацию портов, пока как `\d{1,5}`, но с портами 0-9 это скорее не верно. А валидирую я именно URL - в сети много достаточно четких определений. Выше по комментам я давал ссылку, рекомендую ознакомится!

Comment: `([a-z0-9-]|(?<!\.)\.)` - создает дополнительную группу, в домене `https://web.comandos.ban` во вторую группу попадает буква `s`, не критично, но лучше сделать группу не захватываемой `(?:...)`

Comment: На мой взгляд шаблон сильно усложнен, можно попробовать что-то вроде вот этого `^https?:\/\/([a-z0-9]{2,}(?:\.[a-z0-9]{2,})+(?::\d{1,5})?)$`

Comment: как-то странно работает ... `https://wwww.www.www.www-yy.by:8888` - ловит норм, а `https://ww-ww.www.www.www-yy.by:8888` уже не пропускает.