# Как сделать регулярное выражение для поиска всех URL в тексте?

Tags: python, re

Есть регулярное выражение, которое вытягивает все URL из текста html:

```
r'''http[\:/a-zа-яA-ZА-Я0-9\.\?\=&-]*'''
```

Но оно так же вытягивает и следующие значения:

```
https:
http-equiv=
http
http:
https
https?://
```

Как исправить регулярку, чтобы такие значения не попадали в итоговый список?

Так же она не работает для ссылок, которые начинаются без названия протоколов, т.е. ссылку `www.ria.ru/infografika/` или `ria.ru/infografika/` оно не найдет.

Comment: забить на регулярные выражения и попробовать какой-нибудь специализированный модуль?

Comment: я знаю о существовании специальных модулей, но нужна регулярка

Comment: Молоток удобнее микроскопа для забивания гвоздей

Comment: Регулярка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594686/178988, демонстрация: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1003343/178988.

Comment: @strawdog, какой-нибудь? Ну очень полезный совет.

Comment: @Kromster, какой?

Comment: @Qwertiy, использую Вашу регулярку следующим образом     pattern = "/(https?:\/\/|ftps?:\/\/|www\.)((?![.,?!;:()]*(\s|$))[^\s]){2,}/gim"
    links = re.findall(pattern, text_html), но он ничего не находит. подскажите. что я делаю не так?

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева, перед строкой поставь `r`, чтобы слеши не портились, а js'ные границы и флаги удали: ```pattern = r"(https?:\/\/|ftps?:\/\/|www\.)((?![.,?!;:()]*(\s|$))[^\s]){2,}"```

Comment: @Qwertiy, очень непонятный результат [('https://', '"', ''), ('www.', '"', '')]

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева, ну группы надо было на незахватываемые поменять. Это ж ты на питоне пишешь...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо взять регулярку из [соответствующего ответа](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594686/178988) (работу которой можно [посмотреть тут](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1003343/178988)) и поменять в ней захватываемые группы на незахватываемые, поскольку питон при использовании findall набирает группы если они есть.

Получается так: https://ideone.com/mMj9b3

Программа:

```
import re
pattern = r"(?:https?:\/\/|ftps?:\/\/|www\.)(?:(?![.,?!;:()]*(?:\s|$))[^\s]){2,}"
print(re.findall(pattern, input()))
```

Ввод:

```
Возможно, http://сайт.рф? Ну или http://сайт.рф?id=67 - вроде парсится Ну и не без www.google.ru.
```

Вывод:

```
['http://сайт.рф', 'http://сайт.рф?id=67', 'www.google.ru']
```

Чтобы адреса заканчивались на кавычках: https://ideone.com/VF0As3

```
import re
pattern = r"""(?:https?:\/\/|ftps?:\/\/|www\.)(?:(?![.,?!;:()]*(?:\s|$|"))[^\s"]){2,}"""
print(re.findall(pattern, input()))
```

Ввод:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="ru"><head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article# ya: http://webmaster.yandex.ru/vocabularies/"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><script> Возможно, http://сайт.рф? Ну или http://сайт.рф?id=67 - вроде парсится Ну и не без www.google.ru.
```

Вывод:

```
['http://ogp.me/ns#', 'http://ogp.me/ns/fb#', 'http://ogp.me/ns/article#', 'http://webmaster.yandex.ru/vocabularies/', 'http://сайт.рф', 'http://сайт.рф?id=67', 'www.google.ru']
```

Comment: вытягиваются так же теги </div><a. можете пожалуйста помочь их убрать? (не совсем понимаю как самой это сделать)

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева, пример текста будет?

Comment: @Kromster, в код было обёрнуто потому что это входные данные программы. 3 блока кода: программа, stdin, stdout.

Comment: вот кусочек ```<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru"><head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article# ya: http://webmaster.yandex.ru/vocabularies/"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><script>```. тут захватывает # и ><meta

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева, кавычки исправил, а `#` является частью url - тут всё верно.