# заключить все ссылки в документе в круглые скобки ()

Tags: notepad++

Как заключить все ссылки в документе в круглые скобки () ?

```
(http://ссылка)
```

У меня HTML-таблица, ссылки в ячейках 
Ссылки только такого вида: `http://youtu.be/t3s1STiBxqU`, `https://goo.su/yl0Uqzd`

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>http://youtu.be/t3s1STiBxqU</td>
</tr>
```

Вариант @void именно такие ссылки не оборачивает

```
<td>(http://youtu.be)/t3s1STiBxqU</td>
```

Вариант @Qwertiy оборачивает вместе с тегом

```
<td>(http://youtu.be/t3s1STiBxqU</td>)
```

Отставил тег пробелом, ссылка обернулась, пробел удалил.
Спасибо вам большое, друзья!

Comment: Что пробовал? показывай. Что именно не получилось? И пример - документ до и документ после. С пояснениями. Если возможны несколько разных вариантов - покажи все.

Comment: Протокол только `http` ?

Comment: @Akina, зачем??

Comment: И отдельное спасибо void и Qwertiy за то, что позволяете не вникать в технические детали. Пишу вам, а не наверх - там цензура не пропустит.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Search: `(https?:\/\/[^<]+)` , replace `\($1\)`. Пример обрабатывается корректно. Если какие-то варианты обрабатываются неправильно - надо их видеть, для чего собственно и было написано "покажи все варианты".

Comment: @Akina Ну, так и напиши, что универсального решения нет, и в каждом конкретном случае оно будет своё, индивидуальное. Конечно, если я всё правильно понял.

Comment: Нет, ты понял неправильно. Увы...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Берём регулярку из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594686/178988):

   ```
   (https?:\/\/|ftps?:\/\/|www\.)((?![.,?!;:()]*(\s|$))[^\s]){2,}
   ```
2. Заменяем на

   ```
   \($0\)
   ```

[image: скриншот]

> Вариант @Qwertiy оборачивает вместе с тегом
>
> ```
> <td>(http://youtu.be/t3s1STiBxqU</td>)
> ```

Добавь `<` в запрещённые символы:

```
(https?:\/\/|ftps?:\/\/|www\.)((?![.,?!;:()]*(\s|$|<))[^\s]){2,}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Выглядит очень достойно. Буду разбирать.

Comment: @void, вот тут потыкать можно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1003343/178988.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так. Привожу специально развернутый вариант (не самый оптимальный, когда с использованием \w) - для вашего понимания больше. Пишу "на коленке". Возможно, кто-то представит и более короткую запись.

Ищем
`(http[s]?:\/\/([a-z]{0,}\.?){0,}\??([a-z]{0,}\=?[a-z1-9]{0,}))`

Заменяем на
`\(\1\)`

Проверено для

- `http://www.example.com`
- `https://www.example.com`
- `http://example.com`
- `https://example.com`
- `http://subdomain.example.com`
- `https://subdomain.example.com`
- `https://www.example.com?page=example1`

Если ссылки еще и другого вида, то доработайте по примеру.

Comment: У меня есть лучше регулярка, но всё равно плюсик.

Comment: Вопрос обновился.